# What is a good heuristic funtion in the Multiple Positions Search Problem?

Tags: search, heuristics

Take a simple example: if a dog wants to eat all the food in different locations and there are some obstacles in the search path. Then how can I find a heuristic function in the A star algorithm that can reduce the expanded nodes?

I tried several heuristic functions, but they expanded too many nodes. So I wonder what is the best heuristic you can come up with?

Thanks

Comment: This problem seems equivalent to the traveling salesman problem. So it's unlikely that a good heuristic exists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.